# what value to set in postgresql.conf to enable use of "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" and ip address?

Tags: postgresql

In order to be able to connect to my postgresql database from another machine, I had to configure my postgresql.conf file like so:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '10.14.4.4'                # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

I tried using 127.0.0.1 but that didn't work.  Neither did "localhost".  The only way I was able to do make this work is to use the actual IP address of the server.  I checked to make sure in my "hosts" file, localhost was defined....

In any case, I am now able to connect from a different server by doing the following:

```
psql -U test test -h 10.14.4.4
```

But now I'm noticing that I cannot log on **locally** using the following syntax:

```
psql -U test test -h 127.0.0.1
```

The only way to log in locally is

```
psql -U test test
```

I tried to change my postgresql.conf file to use "*"... and that let's me log in remotely, but locally, i still cannot use 127.0.0.1 or "localhost" to connect.

How can I set this up so that both my remote log ins and my local log ins work?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what my pg_hba.conf file looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             10.14.4.0/24 trust
host    replication     postgres        10.14.0.0/16              trust
```

Comment: Try at http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ also don't forge to mention your OS.

Answer (score 3):

I had to edit the pg_hba.conf file to use MD5, not trust. 
This is what the final file looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             10.14.4.0/24             md5
host    replication     postgres        10.14.0.0/16              trust
```

Now I can log on remotely specifying IP address, and log on locally using IP address too.

Comment: "trust" means no password is needed, "md5" means need MD5 password, so both should have worked if you tried to login locally without a password

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the pg_hba.conf file, see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: I have "Local all all trust" and "host all all 10.14.4.0/24 trust" which should cover both the local server, and the remote server.

Comment: No it isn't 'local' is socket ( Unix-domain ) and 10.14.4.0/24 isn't localhost 127.0.0.1. Remember when you connect to 127.0.0.1, the IP you are arriving from is 127.0.0.1, NOT your real IP. As you are reaching the DB from the "lo" (localhost) interface.

Comment: please check edit 1 in my post